# how to make the key arrows work?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I am using Java and I can't make the key arrows work in the applet , can anyone help me? Here's the code I wrote

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class KeyboardJApplet extends JApplet {
    int weigh = 20;
    int height = 20;
    JLabel c;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                setFocusable(true);
                c.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
                        int e = ke.getKeyCode();
                        /*
                        switch (e) {
                            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                                weigh++;
                                break;
                            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                                weigh--;
                                break;
                            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                                height++;
                                break;
                            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                                height--;
                                break;
                        }
                        */
                        if (e == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                            //c.setLocation(c.getX()+1,c.getY());
                            weigh++;
                            repaint();
                        }
                        if (e == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                            //c.setLocation(c.getX()-1,c.getY());
                            weigh--;
                            repaint();
                        }
                        if (e == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                            //c.setLocation(c.getX(),c.getY()-1);
                            height--;
                            repaint();
                        }
                        if (e == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                            //c.setLocation(c.getX(),c.getY()+1);
                            height++;
                            repaint();
                        }

                    }
                });
                add(c);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        JLabel c = new JLabel("java");
        g.drawString(c.getText(), weigh, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the tutorial on [How to use Key Bindings](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) for that is what you want to use here.

Comment: Also, how did you succeed to produce such a formatting?

Comment: @Ischin, you've added `@Override` to the code (excellent reformatting, thanks), but what if the _absence_ of the `@Override` was the cause of the problem? Reformatting code is an excellent way to improve our site :) but changing each other's code might hide the exact problem from future viewers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should not have a while (true) loop in the init method.

Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel (or JCompnent) and then you add the component to the applets content pane. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more inforamtion and examples.

If you want to respond to key presses then you should use [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), not a KeyListener.

You don't need to create a label and then use getText() to get the text to paint.

I suggest you take time to read the Swing tutorial for the basics.

Comment: what's wrong with the code , i mean , i used the keylistner interface to make the keys work but it doesn't work , i removed the while , and it gives only the word java